# Can't change desktop environment from login screen in 17.10

Tags: 17.10

I have been used to using that to change it, I've installed LXDE in the terminal because base Ubuntu 17.10 DE is making it a bit laggy for HP Stream 11. I need to change the DE but I can't see anything at the login screen to change desktop environment.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

source: [How to Switch from GNOME to Unity in Ubuntu 17.10](https://itsfoss.com/use-unity-ubuntu-17-10/)

Comment: Thanks, sorry that I'm a noob. How do I solve this question or does it solve itself? New user on askubuntu.

Comment: No problem, just click the tick under the down vote.